# Como validar campos unicos con Request personalizados cuando se hace un update

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

EL pequeño problem es probando un formulario de edicion de un usuario, cuando valido los datos con un request personalizado, me genera problemas cuando tengo campos unicos.

En mi caso, tengo el email como campo unico, cuando edito y no quiero modificar el email, me lanza el cartel de que esta tomado.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:60',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    ];
}
```

Lo primero que se me ocurrio fue modificar la regla del Request donde dice que sea unico, pero esto permite que pueda meter un mail que ya esta en la base de datos y no diga nada, esta bien, en mi base de datos esta tambien restringido y no lo mete, pero me gustaria que en ese caso si le avise que esta tomado

lo siguiente que se me ocurrio fue hacer esta parte en el controller, pero no logro comprobrar la existencia del email dentro de la BD, osea si hago un where donde obtengo un users si el email existe o una coleccion vacia si no, pero ahi quedo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación de Laravel este caso se explica:

> unique:table,column,except,idColumn

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique

En caso que necesites algo más complejo la idea es utilizar la clase `Rule` y el método ignore:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

o según el caso:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')
```

Comment: no me quedo claro, esto lo agrego en mi Request? o en el controlador? que seria $data?

Comment: Si vas a usar `Validator::make` sería en el controlador, o el segundo en el Request.

Comment: Agrega `use Validator;`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47125/discussion-between-cidius-and-shaz).

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que unique en método rules, tiene 3 parámetros:

```
public function rules()
{
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->route('user'),
}
```

El primer parámetro define la table
el segundo la columna
el tercero es que fila debe ignorar (con el id de esta)

En este caso si haces un dump and die

```
dd($this)
```

al inicio del método, obtendrás todos los parámetros del request. Como debes saber dentro del request está la ruta a la cual estás tratando de acceder (misitio.com/usuario/edit/{user} => donde {user} es el id del usuario que quieres modificar), por lo tanto con $this->route('user') accedes a la variable {user} escrita en la ruta.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$this->route('users.id'),
```

En el método route, el parámetro "users.id" es el nombre de la ruta resource (en mi caso es users) junto al campo id de la tabla.

Ademas, el método me sirve tanto para insertar como para actualizar.

Si no funciona, has un dd(this->route('users.id') o como se llame la ruta de usuarios mas el id y verifica si efectivamente te está devolviendo el id del usuario.

Saludos.