# Validación de datos en Laravel con update

Tags: laravel, formularios, validación, update

Cómo se puede hacer una **validación de datos** de un formulario en **Laravel** para actualizar un registro de una tabla que contiene un campo único en ella con estas restricciones:

- El campo ha de ser único en toda la tabla
- Si el campo es el mismo valor que ya tenía ese mismo registro que también se actualice.

El problema que hay es que si añado la opción de validación de "unique" si el campo es el mismo, como ya existe ese mismo registro con ese nombre, no me permite realizar el update.

La migración de laravel es esta:

```
    public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('color');
        $table->enum('status', ['disabled', 'enabled']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

La parte del modelo que interesa es esta:

```
    public function updateDepartment($dataDepartment, $id){

    return Department::where('id', $id)->update($dataDepartment);
}
```

La parte del controlador es esta:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate(['name' =>   'required | unique:departments',]);
    
    $dataDepartment = request()->except('_token', '_method');
    $dataDepartment['updated_at'] = now();

    $this->departmentModel->updateDepartment($dataDepartment, $id);
    return redirect('/departments')->with('mensage', 'Department has been updated.');
}
```

Agradezco cualquier idea que se os pueda ocurrir.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como validar campos unicos con Request personalizados cuando se hace un update](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28968/como-validar-campos-unicos-con-request-personalizados-cuando-se-hace-un-update)

Answer (score 0):

Es relativamente fácil lo que quieres y ya tienes la mitad del camino hecho. A diferencia del link que te dejaron en el comentario, existe una manera aún más sencilla y mejor de hacer lo que quieres.

Lo único que debes hacer en tu método validate es agregar la columna que quieres validar más el es campo único, puede ser el `id` del registro o el campo `name`:

**Debes tener bastante cuidado con los espacios, ya que te puede dar error, escribe todo pegado.**

También debes cambiar las comillas simples por dobles en el required.

```
$request->validate(['name' =>   "required|unique:departments,name,$request->name"]);
```

Puedes también utilizar `$request->id`, dependiendo que es lo que estás mandando desde tu formulario.

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!!

Comment: Tendrias que cambiar `$request->name` por `$request->id`. Se usa el parametro de la ruta (o `id` del registro en la tabla de BD) para indicarle al validador cual es el registro que quieres ignorar si no es unico, y no el valor que quieres que sea unico

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido el objetivo, pero me parece muy enrevesado.

Habría alguna forma más optima de hacerlo?? En realidad estaría bien que fuera el mismo validate el que comprobara la similitud con el campo de entrada

aquí va el código que me ha funcionado para lo que quería comentar

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    
    $dataDepartment = request()->except('name', 'color', '_token', '_method');
    
    // si el campo NAME es igual pero el campo COLOR no
    if ( ((Department::where('id',$id)->first())->name == $request->name) & (Department::where('id',$id)->first())->color != $request->color )
        {
            $request->validate(['color' => "required|unique:departments,color"]);
            $dataDepartment['color'] = $request->color;
        }
    // si el campo NAME no es igual pero el campo COLOR si
    if ( ((Department::where('id',$id)->first())->name != $request->name) & (Department::where('id',$id)->first())->color == $request->color )
    {
        $request->validate(['name' => "required|unique:departments,name"]);
        $dataDepartment['name'] = $request->name;
    }
    
    // si el campo NAME y el campo COLOR no son iguales
    if ( ((Department::where('id',$id)->first())->name != $request->name) & (Department::where('id',$id)->first())->color != $request->color )
    {
        $request->validate(['name' => "required|unique:departments,name"]);
        $request->validate(['color' => "required|unique:departments,color"]);
        $dataDepartment['name'] = $request->name;
        $dataDepartment['color'] = $request->color;
    }

    $dataDepartment['updated_at'] = now();

    $this->departmentModel->updateDepartment($dataDepartment, $id);
    
    return redirect('/departments')->with('mensage', 'Department has been updated.');
}
```

Comment: Saludos intentaste con la solución que te di pero con `$request->id` ?

Comment: Eso que te dicen antes. Fijate en el link que te pase debajo de la pregunta, o en la otra respuesta (cambiando `$request->name` por `$request->id`). Tienes que usar el parametro de la ruta para indicarle al validador cual es el registro que quieres ignorar si no es unico. No hay que hacer todo eso manualmente, laravel lo hace automatico si le escribies bien la regla

Answer (score -1):

Gracias por la respuesta!!!
Sin embargo, no funciona.

Si el campo "name" es el mismo, me sigue diciendo que ya hay uno en la base de datos con el mismo nombre.

Me explico.

Pongamos que hay 3 registros de departments, con 3 names "IT, Design, HR"

Si edito IT y le cambio el nombre (que no coincida con ninguno de los restantes), lo acepta. Sin embargo, si edito IT y lo dejo tal cual, me dice que el nombre está en la BBDD y por tanto no hace el update.

El motivo de actualizar el registro de la tabla departments es que pueda añadir campos futuros que sí fueran modificables pero que no cambie el name.

Alguna idea???

Comment: Agrega esto como una edición de la pregunta en vez de en una respuesta. Agrega además el codigo de lo que dices que no funciona.

Comment: Por favor elimina esta respuesta, ya que confunde, porque no es una respesta ¯\_(ツ)_/¯